# Confused about implications and basic logic : A problem with $\lor$ and a contrapositive

Tags: proof-verification, propositional-calculus

Suppose I have a generic function $f$ that satisfies
$$\frac{f(a)}{b} + \frac{f(b)}{a} = \frac{f(a)}{a} + \frac{f(b)}{b}$$
for some $a$ and $b$ in the domain of $f$, with $a \neq b$.  Assume further that $f$ also satisfies
$$\frac{f(a)}{a} < \frac{f(b)}{b}.$$

This then implies that we have the equation
$$f(a) = f(b)$$
since $a \neq b$.

Furthermore, we also obtain
$b < a$
from the inequality mentioned earlier.

Does this imply that the implication
$$b < a \implies f(b) \leq f(a)$$
is true, since both the premise $b < a$ and the conclusion $f(b) \leq f(a)$ are true under the given assumptions?

I am wary that this might not necessarily be the case, because this would imply that the contrapositive
$$f(a) < f(b) \implies a < b$$
is true, which for the current function $f$ that I am studying, I still am not sure if it is indeed true.

Perhaps this dilemma can be resolved by merely stating that $f(b) = f(a)$ and $f(b) \leq f(a)$ are **not logically equivalent** (i.e., they do not encode the same information)?

Any helpful advice that you can offer on this question of mine will be wholeheartedly appreciated!

Comment: Of course : $f(b)=f(a)$ and $f(b)≤f(a)$ are **not** equivalent : if $x=y$, then obviously $x = y \lor x < y$ (that is : $x \le y$). But if $x < y$, then also $x \le y$, but cleraly not $x=y$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA, thank you for your comment.  Which brings me back to my question:  If I know that $b <  a$ and $f(a) = f(b)$ are both true, does it follow that the implication
$$b < a \implies f(b) \leq f(a)$$
is also true?

It appears to be so, since
$$\left(b < a \implies f(b) \leq f(a)\right) \Longleftrightarrow \left(\left(a < b\right) \lor \left(f(a) = f(b)\right) \lor \left(f(b) < f(a)\right)\right)$$
and the propositional form equivalent to the implication is always true because of the true disjunct $f(a) = f(b)$.

Comment: If by "implication" you mean the (truth-functional) *conditional* ("if __, then__"), YES : $TRUE \to TRUE$ is $TRUE$. If you mean *logical implication*, things are different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first equation is equivalent to $f(a)=f(b)$, so this information is independent of the fact that $a>b$. The equality has nothing to do with the inequality, there is no implication here.

Once you have established that $f(a)=f(b)$, then the inequality implies $a>b$.

Notice that you have $f(a)=f(b)$, and not $f(a)\ge f(b)$.

Comment: $b < a$ follows from $1 = \frac{f(a)}{f(b)} < \frac{a}{b}$, does it not?  I am not asking if $f(a) = f(b)$ is independent of $b < a$, I was trying to find out if the implication
$$b < a \implies f(b) \leq f(a)$$
is true under the given assumptions (i.e., equation + inequality).

Comment: I edited the answer to make it more clear.

Comment: But if $f(a) = f(b)$, then $f(b) \leq f(a)$ is true, right?  Because $f(a) = f(b)$ can be decomposed into the conjunction
$$\left(f(a) \leq f(b)\right) \land \left(f(b) \leq f(a)\right).$$
Or perhaps I'm missing something pretty basic?

Comment: By the way, I think your observation that "the equality has nothing to do with the inequality" does not apply in what I am trying to understand in my confusion about the logical OR and the contrapositive.  Does there have to be a relationship between the equality and the inequality?  Given the conditions (i.e., equation + inequality) that I have initially specified in my post, then $f(a) = f(b)$ and $b < a$ both hold.  Perhaps what I am trying to understand is why it *does not follow* that the implication
$$b < a \implies f(b) \leq f(a)$$
is true? (continued)

Comment: Both the premise $b < a$ and the conclusion $f(b) \leq f(a)$ are true, per my previous comments.  So **True** implies **True** and therefore the implication is **True**?  What am I missing?  =(

Comment: The statements $f(a)=f(b)$ and $a>b$ are both true, but they are *independent*. There is no relation of implication between them, and therefore a contrapositive makes no sense. Take the function $f(x)=1$ and the points $a=1$ and $b=2$. Then $f(a)=f(b)$ and $a<b$. So what?

Comment: Okay, let me restate my point of view.  The implication
$$b < a \implies f(b) \leq f(a)$$
is logically equivalent (via Material Implication) to
$$\left(a < b\right) \lor \left(f(b) \leq f(a)\right),$$
which is also logically equivalent to
$$\left(a < b\right) \lor \left(f(b) = f(a)\right) \lor \left(f(b) < f(a)\right).$$
Since $f(a) = f(b)$ is **True** by an underlying assumption (i.e., the equation), then the implication is **True**.  Or am I not making any sense?

Comment: I am asking about the **truth value** of the implication I mentioned, given the individual truth values of the *premise* and the *conclusion*.

Comment: To quote your example, $f(x) = 1$, points $a = 1$ and $b = 2$.  What is the *truth value* of the following propositional form:
$$\left(b < a\right) \lor \left(f(a) = f(b)\right) \lor \left(f(a) < f(b)\right)?$$
Is it not the case that the truth value is **True**, since the disjunct $f(a) = f(b)$ is true?

Additionally, the propositional form
$$\left(b < a\right) \lor \left(f(a) = f(b)\right) \lor \left(f(a) < f(b)\right)?$$
is logically equivalent to
$$\left(a < b\right) \implies \left(f(a) \leq f(b)\right)$$
via a similar argument in my previous comment. Argh!

Comment: The source of your confusion is indeed that your question does not make sense. Maybe there is a mistake in your first equation? Because as written it implies $f(a)=f(b)$, *irrespective* of whether $a>b$ or $a<b$. So *there is no real implication*, understand?

Let me make this very dramatic. The implication $1<2\Rightarrow 0=0$ holds (in a trivial sense). Is the contrapositive true, $0<0 \Rightarrow 1>2$?

Comment: Well yes, **False** implies **False** is **True**, so the contrapositive you have given in your example is true.

Comment: To set the record straight, I am sure that there is no mistake in my first equation.  I will leave the question open for now and will wait for other answers / insights, as the case may be.  Thank you very much for your time, Marcel!  =)